# how can I normalize data frame values by the sum (get percents)

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate, data.table

I have the following data frame:

```
> str(df)
 'data.frame':  52 obs. of  3 variables:
  $ n    : int  10 20 64 108 128 144 256 320 404 512 ...
  $ step : Factor w/ 4 levels "Step1","Step2",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  $ value: num  0.00178 0.000956 0.001613 0.001998 0.002975 ...
```

Now I would like to normalize/divide the `df$value` by the sum of values that belong to the same n i.e. so I can get the percentages. This doesn't work but shows what I would like to achieve. Here I precompute into dfa the sums of the values that belong to the same n and try to divide on the original `df$value` by the aggregated total `dfa$value` with matching `n`:

```
dfa <- aggregate(x=df$value, by=list(df$n), FUN=sum)
names(dfa)[names(dfa)=="Group.1"] <- "n"           
names(dfa)[names(dfa)=="x"] <- "value"
df$value <- df$value / dfa[dfa$n==df$n,][[1]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the following works, using package `data.table`.

```
df <- data.table(df)
df[,value2 := value/sum(value),by=n]
```

Comment: is it really necessary to convert to table? or otherwise can I get it back as data frame? I need it for plotting with ggplot2 ...

Comment: `data.table` extends `data.frame`, so anything you can do to a data frame you can do to a data table. You could even convert it back to a data frame after doing this operation.

Answer (score 4):

I would use `ave`:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(n=rep(c(2,3,6,8), each=5), value = sample(5:60, 20))
df$value_2 <- ave(df$value, list(df$n), FUN=function(L) L/sum(L))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the code you have is this line:

```
df$value <- df$value / dfa[dfa$n==df$n,][[1]]
```

The line `dfa$n==df$n` returns a logical vector of length `max(length(df),length(dfa)` which tells you for each index if the `n` matches. I don't think you can use that to match `dfa$n` to `df$n`.

Using `base` functions, you can use `aggregate` and `merge`:

```
dfa <- aggregate(x=df$value, by=list(df$n), FUN=sum)
names(dfa) <- c("n","sum.value") 
df2 <- merge(df,dfa,by="n",all = TRUE)
df2$value2 <- df2$value/df2$sum.value
```

Comment: If the data is large, the merge step will be very slow.  The `data.table` solution you provided first is much preferable.  And to answer the OP's concern, you can always coerce back to "only" a `data.frame` for `ggplot` with `as.data.frame`

Comment: Understood about efficiency. I suppose this answer was self-indulgent, though seeing multiple ways to do things might not be bad. It looks like OP's dataset is 52 rows, so speed doesn't seem to be a huge concern.

Comment: fwiw, `plyr` is also an elegant solution for smaller data sizes. `library(plyr); ddply(df, .(n), transform, value2 = value / sum(value))`

Comment: I unfortunately have little knowledge of `plyr`, but it does look elegant. I shall have to look into it.